# Angular 2 mat-checkbox inside mat-cell broken on check

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Someone can help me to fix this?

[image: mat-checkbox broken on check]

here is my code:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="checked">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.checked"></mat-checkbox>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

I was searching for a solution on Inspect and realize that when I uncheck the position, and check works normally again.

[image: css property]

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the checkbox position fixed. This should do the trick.

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.checked" class="fixed"></mat-checkbox>

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem comes from the default value of "overflow" property.
Try to set it to **unset**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="checked">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="overflow: unset;">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.checked"></mat-checkbox>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple CSS issue

I solved with this on @Angular/material@5.0.2

```
mat-cell.mat-cell, mat-header-cell.mat-header-cell {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

> Remember to put this style in your styles.css / styles.scss or to handle components encapsulation, otherwise it may not work.